# How to call action in button click of component, Even though i'm using connect function which is not calling in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Here i'm using the postMessage() click event to send the callback to action/reducer but i'm unable to call, please help me out in this i'm new to react redux.thank in advance..

```
    import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';

    export class AddBlogPost extends Component {
        constructor(state) {
            super();       
        }
        postMessage =()=>{
            this.props.postMessage();
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <form>
                    <div className="imgcontainer">
                    </div>
                    <div className="container">
                        <label><b>Username</b></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" onChange={(e) => this.userName = e.target.value} />
                        <label><b>Subject</b></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Subject" name="sub" onChange={(e) => this.subject = e.target.value} />
                        <label><b>Comment/Message</b></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Message" name="msg" onChange={(e) => this.message = e.target.value} />
                        <button type="submit" onClick={(event) => { event.preventDefault(); this.postMessage() }}>Post Message</button>
                        <button type="button" className="cancelbtn" style={{ float: 'right' }}>Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            );
        }
    }
```

this is my proptypes here

```
    AddBlogPost.PropTypes = {   
        postMessage: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }
```

this is my dipatcher

```
    export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        postMessage: () => dispatch({ type: 'ADD_POST' })
    };

    export const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
            state: state
        }
    }

    AddBlogPost = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddBlogPost);

    export default AddBlogPost;
```

Comment: can you show me your reducer?

Comment: @HanaAlaydrus Thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: how do you check whether the action is dispatched or not. You code seems fine

Comment: export const BlogPostReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_COMMENT':
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

Comment: my index file looks like       ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <HomePage />
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

Comment: i'm using route here to load my page as a component={AddBlogPost}

Comment: https://github.com/kumar155/react-redux-blog please check the project here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you miss return?

Try change this

```
export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    postMessage: () => dispatch({ type: 'ADD_POST' })
};
```

To this

```
export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
       postMessage: () => dispatch({ type: 'ADD_POST' })
    }
};
```

Comment: yes it is working now and calling the action thank you,sorry for the silly mistakes in initial days of trying to do my own simple application.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need of following,

```
postMessage =()=>{
  this.props.postMessage();
}
```

And

```
AddBlogPost.PropTypes = {   
        postMessage: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }
```

You can directly send the callback to action like below

```
<button type="submit" onClick={(event) => { event.preventDefault(); this.props.postMessage() }}>Post Message</button>
```